# Facebook/Twitter Share/Like/Retweet Button For Earning Points

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, reward

I have an e-commerce website. I'm thinking to integrate a social media system to my website. I have Facebook integration for Login my system or sharing something from my page.

When I share a product on Facebook or when I share a product on Twitter, I want to bring points to my customers for shopping but I couldn't set any algorithm on my mind and I couldn't any sources in web.

I only thought this algorithm but as I wrote, I couldn't any souce for C#;

**Customer's Role** -> Clicking Share Button On My WebSite - Share Button - Routing To My Controller From View - Checking UserLogin On Controller - If User Logged In, Earning Points To Customer

By the way, I'm developing my website on ASP.NET MVC and using NopCommerce.

If anyone can help me, I will be really appreciated.

Thanks for help and reading.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to develop as a discount plugin. I've developed something similar here: [Pay with a Tweet - nopCommerce Social Sharing Discount Plugin](http://www.pronopcommerce.com/pay-with-a-tweet-nopcommerce-social-sharing-discount-plugin)

I am using a third party solution for the social posting part to make it easier (and they have a comprehensive API).